# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined, on DATATABLE HTML5 PDF export

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, datatable, export

My code is Working Great but when i Try to add a Message on the PDF exported document show me the message

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at Object.customize (<anonymous>:97:42)
    at s.action (buttons.html5.min.js:27)
    at q (dataTables.buttons.min.js:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dataTables.buttons.min.js:14)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

If i dont add the next line `**message: '__MESSAGE__'**`  workis great, but once i add it show me that error.

My code...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            filename: 'reporte'
        },
        {
            **message: '__MESSAGE__',**
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
            title: 'Reporte de Documentos Emitidos',
            header:true,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
            },
            customize: function (doc) {

                var rowCount = doc.content[1].table.body.length;
                for (i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][0].alignment = 'center';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][1].alignment = 'center';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][2].alignment = 'center';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][3].alignment = 'center';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][6].alignment = 'right';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][7].alignment = 'right';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][8].alignment = 'right';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][9].alignment = 'right';
                    doc.content[1].table.body[i][10].alignment = 'center';
                };
                doc.content.forEach(function(content) {
                    if (content.style == 'message') {
                        content.text = 'this is a late created message'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
    });
```

Looking for many posts it is the way to add a Custom Message, why just after adding that line show me that error, seems like is a clean code.
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I am assuming that you are removing the `**` asterisks ?

Comment: yes,,, i just add asterisks for marking the line... first time posting here...

Comment: Have you tried extending BEFORE the `message` ?  `extend: 'pdfHtml5',` THEN `message: '__MESSAGE__',` ?

Comment: yes i did it... same error!!!

Answer (score 1):

As per this [reference](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/titleMessage.html) the key which you should be using should either be

```
messageTop
```

OR

```
messageBottom
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a updated working JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/to068zv7/1/
The index of content which you were looking up was wrong i changed it from `doc.content[1].table.body` to `doc.content[2].table.body`

`doc.content[1]` doesn't contain the `table` object rather it contains your `message` object

Comment: is weird, i add code this code
[extend: 'pdfHtml5',
       messageTop: 'The information in this table is copyright to Sirius Cybernetics Corp.',
       orientation: 'landscape',
       pageSize: 'LEGAL',
       title: 'Reporte de Documentos Emitidos',
       header:true,
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
            }
}
and shows de Message but once i add the customize function of alignmnet, shows me the body error!!!

Comment: seems like i cant use messagetop with an customize

Comment: could you create  a JS fiddle ? The most likely reason for the error is on this line
`doc.content[1].table.body` it could be a error in logic.. would help if you could produce a fiddle

Comment: Comment out the `rowCount` line and the entire first for loop in the customize callback and check if it works

Comment: same error.... adding here the jsfiddle....
https://jsfiddle.net/cnava/0w5uhsvo/1/